# To indirectly and politely ask about something "I wanted to" vs "I would like to"

Tags: expressions, politeness

When asking someone for some information indirectly which one is preferable?

"I wanted to" e.g. `"I wanted to ask your advice on ..."`

"I would like to" e.g. `"I would like to ask about your advice on..."`

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, I barely hear any difference between your two options.  The use of past-tense "wanted" over present tense "want" in the first example could be debated.  However, I feel the most polite way to express this would be "May I ask your advice on ..."

There are some pedantic types out there that would say that all of these are too passive: you are asking permission to ask (i.e. "May I ask you a question?"  "You just did.")

A more assertive statement might be, "If you don't mind my asking, what is your advice on..."